# How can one study a book that has no exercises?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

If this has been asked before I cannot find it. It is generally accepted that one cannot learn mathematics by purely reading it, the general consensus being that one has to do exercises and as many as possible.

The problem is, what does one do when a book has no exercises? Generally, this is because a book is e.g. more of a monograph, but there are cases where it is really recommended one study a text which has no real exercises. The example that comes to mind most readily is EGA, but past a certain point I’m sure this is the case for most topics.

Usually I guess that is the point where you would be doing research with some guidance from an advisor, but if you don’t then all you have is the text in front of you. What can one do with that?

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  Many great texts, like Hardy's Number Theory, lack exercises.  But if you prefer books with exercises, seek those out.

Comment: Ask questions about it here.

Comment: "One cannot learn mathematics by purely reading it" I don't agree. Perhaps it is harder, but I do it all the time

Comment: You can find exercises always online for almost every course. So no problem in reading such a book. Just search for exercises about every new topic you read. This site has a lot of exercises available, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise researching example problems on the internet, or looking at other similar textbooks that would have example problems. Just read from the textbook, then do problems that have been covered there. If you can't find any problems, ask here, explaining what you covered, and perhaps someone can give you some exercises.